# Existence/uniqueness and solution of quasilinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

So I have this question in a textbook that I have been trying to solve for review but I can't $$u_t+uu_x=1$$
$$u(x,t)=t\text{ when } 2x-t^2=0$$
So the book says that the solution does not exist at all for this problem. I will show you my solution. So first of all I parametrize by $t(0)=s,x(0)=s^2/2, u(0)=s$. With these you get the characteristic equations \begin{align}
&\frac{dx}{dr} = u \nonumber \\
&\frac{dt}{dr} = 1 \nonumber \\
&\frac{du}{dr} =1  \nonumber
\end{align}
Using the initial conditions, we get \begin{align}
&x = \frac{r^2}{2}+sr+ \frac{s^2}{2} \nonumber \\
& t = r + s \nonumber \\
&u = r + s\nonumber
\end{align}
Testing the non-characteristic condition we get
$$\frac{\partial (x,t)}{\partial (r,s)}=\begin{vmatrix}
r+s &  r+s\\ 
1 & 1  \notag
\end{vmatrix} = 0$$
So the non-characteristic condition does not hold, and according to the problem I am supposed to check for existence and uniqueness. The non-characteristic condition implies that the solution either doesn't exist or isn't unique. But I get the solution, which just shows that it isn't unique. Did I do something wrong? Or am I interpreting the solution wrong? Since the textbook says it doesn't exist. 
$$ u(x,t)=t=\pm\sqrt{2x}$$

Comment: How can $u $ be equal to $t$ and $\pm\sqrt{2x}$ at the same time for all $x$ and $t$?

Comment: @user474330 You have $x=\frac{(r+s)^2}{2}$ which you can isolate for $r+s$ and $t=r+s$ also. As you can see $u=r+s$ as well, and so it's equal to both.

Comment: So at the point $(x,t) = (2,1)$, what is $u$?

Comment: @user474330 Hmmm it doesn't seem to exist there, because you end up getting $1 = \pm 2$. Is that what it means by it doesn't exist? That makes sense if it is.

Comment: You have a similar problem anywhere $t^2 \neq 2x$. And, yes, that's why the solution doesn't exist.

Comment: @user474330 Even when $t^2=2x$ don't you have a problem? Because of the $\pm$? If just $t^2\neq 2x$ is a problem, couldn't you just say that it exists when $t^2=2x$ then?

Comment: $\pm \sqrt{2x}$ means either $\sqrt{2x}$ or $-\sqrt{2x}$. So this isn't the problem because you can just pick one.

Comment: @user474330 Why does that mean that the solution doesn't work in general? Like I said earlier, can't you just say it exists given the constraints $t^2=2x$? But I guess that would just be the initial conditions, right? Still have to think about that.

Comment: Think about what that would mean for the solution at any fixed point $x$ as time passes.

Comment: @user474330 Oh yeahhh time wouldn't be able to pass in order to preserve the equality. I guess it would be able to flip between $t$ and $-t$, but yeah I understand.

Comment: @imabelian I don't understand why did you write $u(t,x) = t = \pm \sqrt(2x)$ , that is only true in the set $\{2x = t^2\}$. But in any case, $u(t,x) = t$ is a smooth solution of the equation defined everywhere, so it's definitely not true that the equation doesn't have a solution.

Comment: @themaker When you solve the characteristic equations, you get $u=r+s$, $t=r+s$, and $r+s=\pm\sqrt{2x}$. So you have that $u$ is equal to both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
u_t+uu_x=1\\
u(x,t)=t\text{ when } 2x-t^2=0
\end{cases}$$
A solution is :
$$u(x,t)=\frac{x}{t}+\frac{t}{2}$$

Proof :

$\begin{cases} u_x=\frac{1}{t}\\
u_t=-\frac{x}{t^2}+\frac{1}{2}\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad 
u_t+uu_x=-\frac{x}{t^2}+\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{x}{t}+\frac{t}{2} \right)\frac{1}{t} =1$

Thus, the PDE $\quad u_t+uu_x=1\quad $ is satisfied.

And when $2x-t^2=0 \quad\to\quad x=\frac{t^2}{2}\quad;\quad u=\frac{x}{t}+\frac{t}{2} = \frac{\frac{t^2}{2}}{t}+\frac{t}{2} =t$

Thus the condition $\quad u(x,t)=t\quad$ when $\quad 2x-t^2=0\quad$ is satisfied.

So, with the actual wording of the problem, there is a solution. This is apparently in contradiction with the textbook which says that the solution does not exist.

Probably, there is something important missing in the copy of the wording. For example it might be specified that $u(x,t)$ must exist at $t=0$. If this forgotten (or implicit) condition was added, $u(x,t)=\frac{x}{t}+\frac{t}{2}$ would no longer be a correct solution due to the term with $\frac{1}{t}$ .

IN ADDITION :

$u_t+uu_x=1\quad\to\quad$ Set of ODEs for the characteristic curves :
$$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{1}$$
First family of characteristic curves, from 
$\quad \frac{du}{1}=\frac{dt}{1}$
$$u-t=c_1$$

Second family of characteristic curves, from 
$\quad \frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dx}{c_1+t}=\frac{dt}{1}\quad\to\quad c_1t+\frac{t^2}{2}-x=c_2$
$$(u-t)t+\frac{t^2}{2}-x=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE can be expressed on various equivalent forms, for example :
$$(u-t)t+\frac{t^2}{2}-x=F(u-t)$$
In this implicit equation, $F(X)$ is an arbitrary function.
$$(u-t)t+\frac{1}{2}(t^2-2x)=F(u-t)$$

With condition, when $\quad 2x-t^2=0 \quad,\quad u(x,t)=t $ :
$$(u-t)t+\frac{1}{2}(t^2-2x)=F(u-t)=(t-t)t+\frac{1}{2}(0)=F(t-t)$$
$$F(0)=0$$
Thus, the specified condition restricts the infinite set of functions $F(X)$ to a smaller set of functions $F(X)$ with $F(0)=0$ , still infinite.

Among them, for example $F(X)=X \quad\to\quad (u-t)t+\frac{1}{2}(t^2-2x)=(u-t)$

or another example : $F(X)=X^2 \quad\to\quad (u-t)t+\frac{1}{2}(t^2-2x)=(u-t)^2$

For each of these example, solving the implicit equation for $u$ (when possible) leads to a solution of the problem.

The simplest example is with $F(X)=0$ which leads to a particular solution :
$$(u-t)t+\frac{1}{2}(t^2-2x)=0 \quad\to\quad u(x,t)=\frac{t}{2}+\frac{x}{t}$$

This is the particular solution given as an example at the beginning. Of course, they are an infinity of solutions provided by the above implicit equation.

Comment: How do you explain the non-characteristic condition not being upheld though? Did I do something wrong in my calculations?

Comment: What do you mean with $t(0)=s$? So, for you, $t$ is function of a variable. But what variable ?

Comment: I am parametrizing the initial curve. $t(0)$ should be $t_0$ I guess. Like in a similar example in the textbook, they use the condition $u(x,t) = t/2$ when $4x-t^2=0$ with the same PDE and they do the exact same thing.

Comment: You did nothing wrong, but with the parametrization at value $0$ , it supposes that a solution must exists at $t=0$. So, you can find only a solution which exists at $0$ . That is why you don't find the particular solution $u(x,t)=\frac{x}{t}+\frac{t}{2}$ which doesn't exist  at $t=0$.

Comment: So my solution is correct using my assumptions? Using my parametrization you're saying that my solution does not exist right? But if we were to take out the case when $t=0$ it would exist?

Comment: What are you calling "my solution"? Sorry I cannot well understand.

Comment: $u(x,t)=t=\pm\sqrt{2x}$, using the parametrization I wrote up there, and solving the ODE's we get that.

Comment: This is not exactly what I mean in my main answer. This question was discussed a lot in the comments to your question. The aim of my answer was to show that another solution exists at least.

Comment: That is true, but how did you get your solution? In my textbook it says you should only use method of characteristics. Maybe this is a dumb question, but how would you show that another solution exists (or infinitely many) using just characteristics?

Comment: I used an alternative approach of the method of characteristics. I will type it in addition to my first answer.

Comment: How would you come to that conclusion using only method of characteristics though. Since thats all i have been taught so far